# Naraka/hell realms in Buddhism

Tags: theravada, hells

A being is born into a Naraka-Niraya or Hell as a direct result of his or her accumulated actions (karma) and resides there for a finite period of time until that karma has achieved its full result. It is said that the Yamaraja assesses the vices of the sinful and accords judgement, assigning them to appropriate hells as punishment commensurate with the severity and nature of their sins.
Yama dutas also assigned the job of executing punishments on sinners in various hells.
In the Pali canon,the Supreme Buddha states that a person who has ill-treated their parents, ascetics, holy persons, or elders is taken upon his death to Yama.

So how does the karma affect to yamaraja and his servants,yama dutas for thier actions in assignig punishments?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of (i.e. already answered by the answers to) [Where do Hell Guards fall?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14424/254).